# Can a prophet come after Khatm-e-Nabuat?

Tags: quran, khatam-an-nabiyyin

Can a Rasool or Nabi come to this world for reformation ? And bringing the world communities on one platform and belief

Comment: Are you a new muslim?

Answer (score 5):

Muhammad was the last Prophet and no nabi or rasool can come after him.

> Quran states: Sahih International:
>   Muhammad is not the father of [any] one of your men, but [he is] the Messenger of Allah and last of the prophets. And ever is Allah , of all things, Knowing. (33:40)

And from Hadith:

> Volume 4, Book 56, Number 735 :
>   Narrated by Abu Huraira
>   Allah's Apostle said, "My similitude in comparison with the other prophets before me, is that of a man who has built a house nicely and beautifully, except for a place of one brick in a corner. The people go about it and wonder at its beauty, but say: 'Would that this brick be put in its place!' So I am that brick, and I am the last of the Prophets."

So Muhammad was the last Prophet and no nabi will come after him.

But Essa(AS) will come to kill Dajjal and to support the Muslim umma but He wont be in role of Prophet then. Rather He will be a Muslim following teachings of Muhammad(SAW).

**EDITED WITH SOURCE :**

> Abu Huraira  reported that Prophet Mohammad صلى الله عليه وسلم  said,
>   "By the one whose hands my life is in, surely the Son of  Mary عليه
>   السلام will descend amongst you as a just ruler. He will destroy the
>   cross (this could mean that Jesus will put a final end to
>   Christianity), kill the pig (meaning Jesus will outlaw raising pigs)
>   and abolish the Jizya (this tax on Christians & Jews will be abolished
>   because Christianity and Judaism will end.)."   (Sahih Bukhari)

Answer (score 0):

No. *Khatm-e-Nabuat* means that no prophet will come after Prophet Muhammed (SAW) and Muhammed (SAW) is the last prophet.